# Applying WHERE clause when doing a UNION

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am struggling to get this MySQL query to work. I have two tables:

Table 1

```
TYPE | NAME | LAT | LON | ICON
```

Table 2

```
ID | UID | NAME | LAT | LON | ICON
```

I am trying to select all results from Table 1 and only select some results from Table 2. I am trying to apply a `WHERE` clause to Table 2 but it doesn't seem to work.

I read the documentation and it said for a `UNION` to work the number of columns have to be the same. How can I then only select the same number of columns from both tables to be returned but filter the second table by a column only found on that table?

**My (pseudo)Query:**

```
(SELECT name,lat,lon,icon 
FROM Table1)

UNION 

(SELECT name,lat,lon,icon 
FROM Table2
WHERE uid ="1")
```

Comment: what is the result that your expecting

Comment: your query should work as both select has same no. of columns...what is the issue?

Comment: @KP. I want all results from Table 1 and only results from Table 2 where uid is 1.

Comment: @Bruno, does table1 also contain uid?

Comment: No it doesn't, that is my main problem or I could just filter the entire result by uid.

Comment: so what is the problem with this query? it seems valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION
SELECT
    NULL AS `type`,
    `name`,
    `lat`,
    `long`,
    `icon`
FROM table2 WHERE uid = 1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a942/8

This selects everything from table1, and only where `uid = 1` from table2.

An `UNION` can only be performed if both row sets have the exact same columns. Since there is no `type` column in `table2`, we select a `NULL` and name it `type` so we can do the `UNION`.

Comment: It works! I need to read up more on using `NULL AS 'TYPE'`! Thank you so much! Thanks for explaining it to me too :)

Comment: yes it is like `SELECT  'whatever-value' AS 'whatever-pseudo-column-name'` comes in handy with union and different tables :D

Comment: Makes perfect sense :)